# Syntax for kafkacat to consume specified range of records

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

This [kcat repo](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat) has an example of how to read the last N `(=2000)` records in a Kafka topic (`syslog` in this case):

```
$ kcat -C -b mybroker -t syslog -p 0 -o -2000 -e
```

The parameter `-o` is offset from the end of the topic, and `-e` indicates till the end of the topic. If I want to stream from one specific position `Nth` to another position `(N + k)th`, without knowing the full length of the topic, what would be the syntax?

I am trying to do some sort of random sanity-check on a data being produced where the data is too large to consume all. I wish to do this by randomly consuming a range of data and validate it. Hence, this question.

Comment: Thanks. It's ```-c``` to limit the number of messages ([this article](https://dev.to/de_maric/learn-how-to-use-kafkacat-the-most-versatile-kafka-cli-client-1kb4). Closing this question.

Comment: You can run `kcat` on its own to see all the supported options... You can answer your own post down below to "close it"